# Is this reaction even allowed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model

$$p+p\rightarrow p+n+\pi^+$$

According to coservation laws, is this Allowed or Forbidden?

If Allowed what type of interaction is this :- Strong, EM. or Weak?

Why?

From conservation of Charge & Baryon No. I suggested my friend that it's allowed.
But he suggested that the spin conservation (not isospin) doesn't allow it?
Is this even correct?
Which approach should I follow?
Then to find the nature should I do?

Comment: You bet. Strong. [Routine](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140%2Fepja%2Fi2008-10721-4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and the same basic reaction can also do p+p → d+Π<sup>+</sup>

This is a basic nuclear force reaction, so on your list, strong.